# is it possible to recognize in android/Java if a string text is written from Right to left?

Tags: android, text, unicode, right-to-left

I'm writing an android application, and i need to recognize if the text i have in a String is written in a language that is RTL(right to left) ? 
Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, there is no in-built tools for that, what you may need to do is, split the string with space and check with any dictionary api that it is valid word or not.

Comment: I need it because RTL text may not be shown at all, cut or just not aligned to the right. I would like to align it to the right according to the text content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

A/ http://pastebin.com/e276zn6y Javascript code to determine the script of a character. Should give you an idea. And with the help of:

B/ ftp://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/extracted/DerivedBidiClass.txt

```
# Bidi_Class=Right_To_Left
0590          ; R # Cn       <reserved-0590>
05BE          ; R # Pd       HEBREW PUNCTUATION MAQAF
05C0          ; R # Po       HEBREW PUNCTUATION PASEQ
05C3          ; R # Po       HEBREW PUNCTUATION SOF PASUQ
05C6          ; R # Po       HEBREW PUNCTUATION NUN HAFUKHA
05C8..05CF    ; R # Cn   [8] <reserved-05C8>..<reserved-05CF>
05D0..05EA    ; R # Lo  [27] HEBREW LETTER ALEF..HEBREW LETTER TAV
```

[...] truncated

which gives you the direction of all blocks (showing the beginning to the RTL section), you can figure out the rest.

EDIT:
You might also want to check for Right-To-Left format characters (U+20xx), see http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2000.pdf

Answer (score 7):

Check if the given String is written in RTL by checking if the very first character is within the range of RTL unicode characters.

```
  public static boolean checkRtl ( String string ) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(string)) {
        return false;
    }
    char c = string.charAt(0);
    return c >= 0x590 && c <= 0x6ff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the android document, A [Bidi](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Bidi) object provides information on the bidirectional reordering of the text used to create it. This is required, for example, to properly display Arabic or Hebrew text. These languages are inherently mixed directional, as they order numbers from left-to-right while ordering most other text from right-to-left.

```
Bidi bidi = new Bidi( myString, Bidi.DIRECTION_DEFAULT_LEFT_TO_RIGHT );

if( bidi.isLeftToRight() ) {
   // myString is LTR
} else {
   // myString is RTL
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this already natively supported in Java?

```
/**
* Determine if String is right-to-left (RTL).
* Example of RTL languages: Arabic, Hebrew, etc
*/
private boolean isRTL(String s) {
   for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
       byte d = Character.getDirectionality(s.charAt(i));
       if (d == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT ||
           d == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT_ARABIC ||
           d == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT_EMBEDDING ||
           d == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT_OVERRIDE
       ) {
           return true;
       }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check that by using the Bidi class

```
   private fun isTextRTL(text: String?): Boolean {
    val bidi = Bidi(text, Bidi.DIRECTION_DEFAULT_LEFT_TO_RIGHT)
    return bidi.isRightToLeft
}
```